# Swift - suggestion of CoreData implement for 2 data models

Tags: swift, core-data

I am working on an app that I need to manage persistency for 2 data models.

The app is as simple as it will let me add courses I am taking first, then for each course, I will add some tasks to do.

Courses will display in a TableView, tapping on a course will show tasks in another screen which is also a table view.

I have made CoreData work for CourseModel, I think I will need TaskModel to keep Task table persistent but I am stuck at how to make them work together.

This is CourseModel: works with Course Table

```
Course
    courseCode: String
    courseTitle: String
    courseDesc: String
    list: CourseList (To One, inverse: members)

CourseList
    members: Course (To Many)

CourseData
    courseCode: String
    courseTitle: String
```

This is TaskModel: works with Task Table

```
Task
    taskTitle: String
    taskDueDate: String
    taskTag: String
    list: TaskList (To One, inverse: members)

TaskList
    members: Task (To Many)

TaskData
    taskTitle: String
    taskDueDate: String
```

I am using Swift and CoreData (not SQLite).

Anyone please suggest me a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as simple enough as this:

```
Course
courseCode: String
courseTitle: String
courseDesc: String
tasks: Task (To Many, inverse: course)

Task
course: Course (To One, inverse: tasks)
```

A Course has many tasks and a Task belongs to a Course.

Answer (score 0):

After staying up this night, I found a simple solution:

- Just keep using the two data models like that, but do not create each model in the separate `xcdatamodeld` files.
- Create entities all in the same `xcdatamodeld`, then in the app, we can always control when and how to pass the `managedObjectContext` to the `ViewController` the we need to update `CoreData`
- Then if I want to make the two models work together, I can use flow-control statements and conditions to manage data

I did apply this solution in my app and it works as intended